# What's with the lack of voting?

Tags: discussion

I only joined the site 11 days ago; despite spending a lot of time reading StackOverflow and various other StackExchange sites in the past I haven't felt like I've had much to add elsewhere but as I'm actively working on an Ethereum private chain and projects for my day job I feel I can actually add some minor value here, so this is my first time signing up and contributing to any SE site.

I'm struck by the lack of voting action on this site - in the [users page](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters) I'm up at the top of the voting count despite only just getting here - what's up with that?

Comment: https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/vote-early-vote-often has been "featured" few times in the past.  Do we think that it should continue to be featured?  Or a new one written and featured?

Comment: would it be a daft idea to feature a larger link to it as our first [community promotion ad?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/563/community-promotion-ads-2018)

Comment: It would be interesting if the ad did work a little...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. IMO there are many new users with no previous experience with SE
   sites.
2. Ethereum community is growing fast and unpredictable sometimes,
   meaning that many new users just don't know what they are looking
   for or how to behave.

It is understandable, this field of knowledge is new and it will take time for more people to get used to this technology and to share the same set of fundamental knowledge. And when it happens we will see more answers getting upvoted just because there will be much more people who understand topics of the questions and can see whether the answer is valuable or not.

Summarizing, general knowledge and experience will lead to more active community.

Comment: Fully agree with this answer. Can't count how many times, I've answered for new SE users.

Comment: Also many people don't care in voting once the found the answer. Among the 30 persons I work with, we are about 2 or 3 to vote when we find something useful on stackexchange sites.